# Colorify text in specific words like IDE

Tags: android

I want to build a basic text viewer app which can colorify the code for .c or .java or .py files, I have tried text color span before but that's not the most ideal method to do that. Any clues?

example: 
[image]

to load the .c or .java file into apps activity

```
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="content"
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="file"
                    android:host="*"


android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

This is how I'm coloring each set `span(context,R.color.grey,"[/*]([^[/]]*)[*/]");` (Regx)

```
private static void span(Context context, int color, String word) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(word).matcher(spannableString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(color)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you parsing your .c, .java, .py in the first place?

Comment: That's really the only way to do the onscreen part.

Comment: i'm loading the file in the activity using `intent filter`

Comment: could you add some of the relevant code, please?

Comment: plesae check it now

Comment: have you created a viewer class for these files? This is more what I had in mind with my original question about parsing.

Comment: Yes I have created that viewer class

Comment: Could you add that code as well? Chances are the colour formatting would happen as you're parsing the files.

Comment: yes i've added the main method code, check it now

Comment: can you use webview?

Comment: Yes I can but is it possible??